# How can I check which Facebook users "allowed" my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get a list of facebook users that "allowed" my facebook connect app. (I asked for email, publish_stream)

Comment: You can write the user id's in a database after they successful approve your app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a facebook developer site link.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fpermissions
If user allow your app then it will return result with following settings

```
                [installed] => 1
                [status_update] => 1
                [photo_upload] => 1
                [video_upload] => 1
                [email] => 1
                [create_note] => 1
                [share_item] => 1
                [publish_stream] => 1
                [publish_actions] => 1
                [user_birthday] => 1
                [user_photos] => 1
                [user_status] => 1
```

If user skip step of allow post on facebook then result will be

```
                [installed] => 1
                [email] => 1
                [user_birthday] => 1
                [user_photos] => 1
                [user_status] => 1
```

You can use [publish_stream] => 1 and [publish_actions] => 1 for checking of user was allowed app or not.